# Using SED to substite a specific line with command output

Tags: unix, sed, csh

I am trying write a wrapper for the top command and replace some information it gives me with more useful information. More specifically I want to replace the memory usage information it gives with the information from the swap command.

here is the code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/csh

# files and directories
# /user/bin for who, cut, sort, ps, sed, cat, rm, mv, grep, echo, hostname, swap
set ubin="/usr/bin"

# tmp files and directory
set dir="/tmp"
set TopData=$dir/"Topdata"
set SwapData=$dir/"SwapData"

while ( 1 == 1 )
        swap -sh > $SwapData
        $ubin/top -b |sed -e "5s@.*@$SwapData@g" > $TopData
        $ubin/clear
        $ubin/cat $TopData
        $ubin/sleep 2
end
```

In this example I was trying to use SwapData as a temp file to hold the information but $SwapData just gives the path to the file not the data obviously and I cannot use the swap command directly within the sed (or any command for that matter) argument either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your loop:

```
SwapData=`swap -sh`
```

Also, why are you writing in `csh`?